Single-element range
Given a function that accepts a range, for example:
void f(const std::ranges::range auto& r);

Sometimes I have only one element that I want to pass to the function.
There are multiple ways of creating a single-element range for this purpose, for example:
int i{};

/*1*/ f(std::array{i});
/*2*/ f(std::span{&i, 1});
/*3*/ f(std::ranges::views::single(i));

All of those work, but I'd like to know if there are practical differences (efficiency?) between them and if any of them (or a different one) should be preferred.
(The question is tagged with both C++20 and C++23 in case there are differences between the versions that affect the answer)

Unless you're creating lots of single-element ranges, does it really matter if there are efficiency differences? Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

@Alex O — even though I cannot be 100% sure about possible different performances, I doubt the cases can present any difference. This is why: C++ compilers haven't been so stupid for a long, long time. :-) Besides, such things generally depend on the particular compiler implementation.

@Barmar — please don't mix up two very different things: 1) premature (or redundant) optimization, and 2) the desire of people to learn things and get to the roots of technology. The question assumes that our inquirer wants to sort out things, this is only for good.

I'd follow following rules in general: if you are about to pass a single-element the range - no big matter what exactly you use. Just remember to pass it by reference. Otherwise, just pass that single element by reference, or by value if that's fundamental type.

@SergeyAKryukov is right, I am curious as to what goes on under the hood.

@Alex O — It's always a good idea to look under the hood and/or think about it. That's why I objected to Barmar's post — no matter how insignificant the CPU time cost is, understanding things is more important.

std::views::single is designed to have exactly one element. Even if current implementation is not as optimized as it gets, in a few reiterations of the same platform it will be. From a program design and maintenance perspective, it also reflects the intention of developer. Other methods might mislead the future reader that empty or longer ranges are acceptable as well.

@Red.Wave, All range sizes are acceptable. The question was about the differences between various methods to pass a given single element as a range.

I didn't mean the interface of f. The type that you choose is a hint for future revision and refactoring. If you choose single, then the reviewer is supposed to think trice before sending 2 or more elements. Using an array may hint that future revisions can send more elements.

@Red.Wave, we might have a miscommunication here.  Sending multiple elements (usually a container) is the normal usage.  In one place, I have a single element without a container, but the interface expects a range. Maybe that code will change in the future and we'll have more than one element, only the Agile gods know.

If you need to store a range adaptor constructed from r, e.g. std::views::concat(r, something):

If r is an lvalue of std::array{i}: Because std::array does not model view, the resulting range adaptor will store a pointer to r.
If r is std::span{&i, 1}: The resulting range adaptor will store a copy of r, which contains a pointer to i.
If r is std::views::single(i): The resulting range adaptor will store a copy of r, which contains a copy of i.

If r is an rvalue of std::array{i}, the range adaptor will also store a copy (effectively equivalent to std::views::single(i), but with an extra wrapper).
In general, I'd recommend to use std::view::single(i) because it's least likely to produce dangling pointers, unless the object i is very expensive to copy.

If the element is cheap to copy, then there is not much difference between the three.
If the element is move-only, then std::move is necessary to move it to either the array or the single_view, since them both own the the element. If you don't want to modify the original element, then just use span<const T>.
If the element is neither copyable nor movable, then using a span<T> or span<T, 1> is a more appropriate choice, which can be made by simply taking the address of an element:
T i{};

f(std::span{&i, 1}); // span<T>
f(std::span{&i, std::integral_constant<size_t, 1>{}}); // span<T, 1> in C++26

